# Never web developed - Is this logic correct?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I recently looked into web developing and based on my research I would like to make a series of statements regarding code. If someone knowledgeable can tell me why the statements are not correct, or tell me they are correct, that would help :).

My statements are:

Generally, PHP cannot run in an HTML file, However, HTML and PHP can both exist in a file as long as the file type is PHP.

Generally, You cannot run a server-side script on a client-side HTML file in ANY case, however: you can run HTML in a server-side scripting language.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. Mostly. A small correction, though: HTML isn't actually "run" or "executed" as it's not actually a programming language. HTML is what we call "markup", which is just a way to add structure and organize the information on your screen. CSS adds styling to that structure so it looks prettier. JS is the actual programming language that runs in the browser.

There are, at a very basic level, two parts to a website: the web server, and the web browser. Code that runs on the web server does not run on the web browser and vice versa.

PHP runs purely on the web server. You can use it to generate anything you want and send it to the web browser. For example, PHP can generate HTML, CSS, and JS, and send all of those to the web browser to be run on the client's personal device. That HTML, CSS, and JS will not affect anything on the web server and will never run on the web server, either; however, you can use JS to send any number of additional requests from the web browser back to the web server so that the web server can run more code on the client's behalf.

Websites generally rely on that constant back and forth between web browsers sending a request to the web server and the web server processing that request and sending some result back to the web browser. For example, the web browser says "log me in", then the web server checks your login information and either sends back an error or logs you in and tells you you're good to go.

This is simplified quite a bit, but generally it's true and it's sufficient for what you're asking.

Comment: That extends beyond the scope of what is actually wanted. While it's true that there are exceptions, the traditional and widespread model is the simple client-server relationship. I've also left out information about CDNs, third-party integrations, and other various little bits and pieces because they're not relevant for someone who has never so much as touched web development and just needs the bare basics.

Answer (score 1):

Your statements -
(1) "Generally, PHP cannot run in an HTML file, However, HTML and PHP can both exist in a file as long as the file type is PHP."
**Correct**

(2) "you can run HTML in a server-side scripting language"

HTML is not to meant to "run". Server sends HTML to requesting client and then it is presenting your content with various HTML tags in a formatting those tags are meant for. How exactly those tags will present your content in the user's browser is slightly different from browser to browser.